# How can I use the 'overwritePermissions' function to either turn on a certain channel's permissions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to be able to type "$unlock" and unlock a certain channel's permission. I don't know how to turn the ID into a text channel ID.

```js
switch (args[0]) {
        case "unlock":
        if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Unlockable")) return message.channel.sendMessage('You do not have permission to use this command.')

          const textChannell = ('607370435553918977');
          if (!textChannell) {
            console.log('Please support a unlock channel ID.');
          }
        textChannell.overwritePermissions(message.author, { //I also want to change the everyone role, not just the author of the message

          SEND_MESSAGES: true,
          VIEW_CHANNEL: true
        })
          .then(updated => console.log(updated.permissionOverwrites.get(message.author.id)))
    break;
    }
```

I want it to change the textchannell's ID permissions, but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: textChannell.overwritePermissions is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning the id to a variable like such

```
const testChat = '607370435553918977';
client.channels.get(testChat).overwritePermissions
```

Comment: I have the extra l because I have it defined as something else earlier in the code.

Comment: @MrAuro I have edited my answer. This code currently works in a bot of mine.